# RTKGPS+ : Could we use the mobile device as a rover?

Tags: gps, android, rtkgps+

Using an Android (version 9) based smartphone, I installed RTKGPS+ ( https://github.com/eltorio/RtkGps ) from the play store.

I wonder if it's possible to use the internal GPS chip of the smartphone itself *as the rover* in the "Enable rover" tab from the "Input streams" menu?

If yes, how to set up all options, like "antenna", "stream settings" and so on...?

If no, is it possible to directly plug an external antenna on the smartphone?

Comment: you can use dev mode (debugging) to get the data in real-time > https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options#debugging

Comment: does this mean I have to develop an app to access the raw data?
and what are the raw data in case of the GPS chip? Does it use any standard or is it described somewhere?